# PHP preg_replace to insert string inside an existing string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Unfortunately I really cannot get my head around regular expressions so my last resort is to ask the help of you fine people.

I have this existing code:

```
<li id="id-21" class="listClass" data-author="newbie">
    <div class="someDiv">
        <span class="spanClass">Some content</span>
    </div>

    <div class="controls faint">
        <a href="link2">Link 2</a>
        <a href="link3">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Due to a number of reasons, I have to use preg_replace to inject an additional piece of code:

```
<a href="link1">Link 1</a>
```

I think you can guess where that should go, but for the sake of clarity, my desire is for the resulting string to look like:

```
<li id="id-21" class="listClass" data-author="newbie">
    <div class="someDiv">
        <span class="spanClass">Some content</span>
    </div>

    <div class="controls faint">
        <a href="link1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="link2">Link 2</a>
        <a href="link3">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Can anyone help me with the appropriate regular expression to achieve this?

Comment: You'd better more precise. Do you mean you just want to insert `<a href="link1">Link 1</a>` in front of `<a href="link2">Link 2</a>` ???

Comment: Don't use regex to parse/manipulate HTML. Get a proper HTML parser.

Comment: @Alvin Wong True, Regex **cannot** parse arbitrary HTML. period.

Comment: @luiges90 Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: I'm manipulating HTML templates that are later compiled and parsed in the software that I am using. Don't get too hung up on the HTML side of things. If my example wasn't HTML and was just an arbitrary string, how would I achieve this with regex?

Comment: @luiges90 Except OP's HTML isn't *arbitrary*, is it? :->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$html = '<li id="id-21" class="listClass" data-author="newbie">
    <div class="someDiv">
        <span class="spanClass">Some content</span>
    </div>

    <div class="controls faint">
        <a href="link2">Link 2</a> 
        <a href="link3">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</li>';


$eleName = 'a';
$eleAttr = 'href';
$eleAttrValue = 'link2';
$addBefore = '<a href="link1">Link 1</a>';

$result = regexAddBefore($html, $eleName, $eleAttr, $eleAttrValue, $addBefore);

var_dump($result);

function regexAddBefore($subject, $eleName, $eleAttr, $eleAttrValue, $addBefore){
    $regex = "/(<\s*".$eleName."[^>]*".$eleAttr."\s*=\s*(\"|\')?\s*".$eleAttrValue."\s*(\"|\')?[^>]*>)/s";
    $replace = $addBefore."\r\n$1";

    $subject = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $subject);

    return $subject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two things (Although I couldn't understand your problem clearly)

```
$newStr = preg_replace ('/<[^>]*>/', ' ', $htmlText);
```

this will remove all the html tags from the string. I don't know if it will be usefull for you.

Another recommendation would be to use `strip_tags` function. The second parameter of `strip_tags` is optional. You can define the tags you want to keep with the help of 2nd parameter.

```
$str = '<li id="id-21" class="listClass" data-author="newbie">
        <div class="someDiv">
            <span class="spanClass">Some content</span>
        </div>

        <div class="controls faint">
            <a href="link2">Link 2</a>
            <a href="link3">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        </li>';

echo strip_tags ($str,'<a>');
```

This will give you an output just with the links and whatever text in the html string.

Sorry if this also doesn't help.

Comment: The software I'm working with doesn't work like that, unfortunately. Your solution would definitely work in normal cases but essentially I'm working to create a plugin and manual template edits aren't workable. The big chunk of code is the raw template code that I can pull out of the database and my only option is to work out some regex to inject the     <a href="link1">Link 1</a> code into that. The software later parses it and does whatever it needs to do to make the HTML work. I just need to get that link in there. Thank you so much for taking the time to reply.

Comment: ok then see the new answer. Is that what you are searching for? I tried to understand the problem but may be I am not good with it.